# Moving average on pandas.groupby object that respects time

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

Given a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
toy = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [1,2,3,
       1,2,3,
       1,2,3],
'date': ['2015-05-13', '2015-05-13', '2015-05-13', 
         '2016-02-12', '2016-02-12', '2016-02-12', 
         '2018-07-23', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-23'],
'my_metric': [395, 634, 165, 
              144, 305, 293, 
              23, 395, 242]
})
# Make sure 'date' has datetime format
toy.date = pd.to_datetime(toy.date)
```

[image]

The `my_metric` column contains some (random) metric I wish to compute a time-dependent moving average of, conditional on the column `id` 
and within some specified time interval that I specify myself. I will refer to this time interval as the "lookback time"; which could be 5 minutes 
or 2 years. To determine which observations that are to be included in the lookback calculation, we use the `date` column (which could be the index if you prefer).

To my frustration, I have discovered that such a procedure is not easily performed using pandas builtins, since I need to perform the calculation conditionally 
on `id` and at the same time the calculation should only be made on observations within the lookback time (checked using the `date` column). Hence, the output dataframe should consist of one row for each `id`-`date` combination, with the `my_metric` column now being the average of all observations that is contatined within the lookback time (e.g. 2 years, including today's date).

For clarity, I have included a figure with the desired output format (apologies for the oversized figure) when using a 2-year lookback time:

[image: Desired result using a 2 year lookback time]

I have a solution but it does not make use of specific pandas built-in functions and is likely sub-optimal (combination of list comprehension and a single for-loop). The solution I am looking for will not make use of a for-loop, and is thus more scalable/efficient/fast.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some tinkering I found an answer that will generalize adequately. I used a slightly different 'toy' dataframe (slightly more relevant to my case). For completeness sake, here is the data:

[image]

Consider now the following code:

```
# Define a custom function which groups by time (using the index)
def rolling_average(x, dt):
    xt = x.sort_index().groupby(lambda x: x.time()).rolling(window=dt).mean()
    xt.index = xt.index.droplevel(0)
    return xt

dt='730D' # rolling average window: 730 days = 2 years

# Group by the 'id' column
g = toy.groupby('id')

# Apply the custom function
df = g.apply(rolling_average, dt=dt)

# Massage the data to appropriate format
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset=['id', 'date'])
```

The result is as expected:

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I'm not too happy with this solution in terms of performance. If there are several entries with the same 'id' and 'date' (but different values of 'my_metric') then for each id-date "replicate" the dataframe will get an extra row with intermediate results -- hence the application of 'drop_duplicates' in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

**Calculating lookback time: (Current_year - 2 years)**

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import parser
import datetime

In [1691]: dt = '2018-01-01'

In [1695]: dt = parser.parse(dt)

In [1696]: lookback_time = dt - relativedelta(years=2)
```

**Now, filter the dataframe on lookback time and calculate rolling average**

```
In [1722]: toy['new_metric'] = ((toy.my_metric + toy[toy.date > lookback_time].groupby('id')['my_metric'].shift(1))/2).fillna(toy.my_metric)

In [1674]: toy.sort_values('id')
Out[1674]: 
        date  id  my_metric  new_metric
0 2015-05-13   1        395       395.0
3 2016-02-12   1        144       144.0
6 2018-07-23   1         23        83.5
1 2015-05-13   2        634       634.0
4 2016-02-12   2        305       305.0
7 2018-07-23   2        395       350.0
2 2015-05-13   3        165       165.0
5 2016-02-12   3        293       293.0
8 2018-07-23   3        242       267.5
```

Comment: Where is `2-year lookback time` ?

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Mayank; but as @jezrael pointed out, this will not generalize at all. If we have more than 1 observation (in addition to the current) that falls within the lookback time, then this formula breaks down completely.

Comment: I guess the challenge lies in the fact that we do not a priori know how many rows that fall within the lookback time -- I have looked at pandas window functions, but they do not work properly on grouped dataframes, for some reason.

Comment: @Magnus Sharing my updated answer in a while with lookback time included.

Comment: @Magnus Please check my updated answer. Also, I've taken `lookback time` to last 2 years, which excludes the rows with dates from `2015` from your dataframe. My output is based on that.

Comment: @Mayank; I think you're misunderstanding the fact that the lookback-time in my question is set dynamically, i.e., for the datetime at a given row, the lookback time is calculated from that particular date. For example, when the date = '2016-02-12', the window will be defined from start = 2016-02-12 - 2 years = 2014-02-12, to end = 2016-02-12. I hope I added some clarity here...