# pandas.DataFrame.rolling summing the current row value and the next 2 row value based on Id and time index, to the 1st row's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scipy

**GOAL**

I want to sum the current row value and the next 2 row value based on ID and time index to the 1st row value. Time index moves forward with a 3day window while the summed values can only have the same ID

**The current incorrect functioning**

- 1st row Value SUMMED VALUE = 1st row Value
- 2nd row value SUMMED VALUE = 1st row value + 2nd row Value
- 3rd row Value SUMMED VALUE = 3rd row Value + 2nd row Value + 1st row Value

**CODE**

```
gr = current_df.groupby("id").rolling('3D').rolling_sum_3.sum()
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(gr)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Goal is the following**

- A.) 1st row Value SUMMED VALUE = 3rd row Value + 2nd row Value + 1st row Value
- B.) if there is no 2nd or 3rd row value in this ID and 3 day timeframe just leave this field with a NaN value
- A.) 2nd row value SUMMED VALUE = 2nd row Value + 3rd row Value + 4th row Value
- B.) if there is no 3rd or 4th row value in this ID and 3 day timeframe just leave this field with a NaN value
- etc.

**I have tried**

- using if and for cycles -> runs for very long
- I need  to keep this quick pandas format and have to change maybe the rolling window's **win_type** property [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) so I can maybe roll the window the why I  want but I  don't fully understand these options - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.windows.html#module-scipy.signal.windows
- I can not shift everything up because there are multiple month difference between the happenings and the goal is to just sum values that are in 3 days range to each other
- Nan values are at the top not at the bottom - [how to get a continuous rolling mean in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606531/how-to-get-a-continuous-rolling-mean-in-pandas)
- No grouping - [ValueError: index must be monotonic when applying rolling("2H").mean()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421871/valueerror-index-must-be-monotonic-when-applying-rolling2h-mean)
- as I have mentioned before using for and if is not realy an option because that slows down the computation and I have couple hundreds of thousands of rows. Currently it takes 3s. With similar to those methods in the answer even 20 min - [Moving average on pandas.groupby object that respects time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609003/moving-average-on-pandas-groupby-object-that-respects-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reversing the series and then taking a sum using a rolling window of 3.
- The backwards looking rolling sum will then be a forward looking rolling sum because you reversed the sorting order